# How can I get PHP to compile a LaTeX document if it (www-data) can't get access to the required packages?

Tags: php, ubuntu, latex, pdflatex

I have a PHP script that compiles LaTeX documents with the use of:

```
exec('cd /path/to/doc && /usr/bin/latexmk -pdf filename.tex');
```

This is working for some of my LaTeX documents but my latest document doesn't compile and a look at the log reveals:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ecrm1000): Font ecrm1000 at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Which I have found is the result of LaTeX not being able to see the required font packages. When I run the same compile command under my username the document compiles as it should. So my question is, how can I get PHP (executing as www-data) to get access to the necessary LaTeX packages?

I have tried installing the required package under the www-data account using:

```
sudo -u www-data sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

but it askes for www-data's password, which I don't believe was set by me and isn't anything I've thrown at it.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 if it's any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo mktexpk --destdir /usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ecrm1000`

... makes the font available for all users (same as in missingfont.log but with --destdir argument).

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was wanting - thank you. No more temporary compilation directory!

Answer (score 1):

I run with similar problem and it was solved by setting `$HOME` environment variable to `/var/www` in a shell-script which invoked `pdflatex` (or I believe any folder writeable to `www-data` is ok here). See the details on [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289251/mktextfm-fails-when-pdflatex-is-invoked-by-cgi-bin-script-under-www-data-apache/289252#289252).

Answer (score 0):

You are right with the `sudo` idea, but to get around the password problem, there is a simple solution.

www-data must be in the sudoers list, at `etc/sudoers`, and within this list you can define how the super commands are controlled. It is possible to set www-data as a sudoer that doesn't require a password... but that's not a very clever idea in terms of security. Therefore, in the sudoers list, you can specify what commands are allowed to be executed by the user. Allowing only the `/usr/bin/latexmk` command will get around security problems, and allow your webserver to run super commands without a password.

Check out this help page for Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers - most notably the NOPASSWD section.

The example in your case would be:

```
# This lets "www-data" user run a command without a password
www-data mark-computer= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/latexmk
```

Comment: Boy oh boy that caused some problems with my ability to sudo. I'll leave editing that file for now. Were you suggesting that adding that would allow www-data to have access to the packages it needed for the Latex document to compile or to allow me to use apt-get install to install the packages under www-data? If the latter, would I not need to have something like `www-data mark-computer= NOPASSWD: apt-get`?

Comment: @MarkJones Yes, the commands after NOPASSWD will be allowed without a password. You can change them to whatever works for you.

Comment: Do you *really* want `www-data` in the sudoers list? It creates such a thin wall between the whole of the Internet, and root access to your entire machine. It doesn't make the application any less secure, but the damage that can be done by ANY chink in your application security would be immense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what eventually got the compilation working.

Under my own home folder was a hidden folder that LaTeX was using to store the fonts it needed `~/.texmf-var`. This folder contained `fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec` and in there were 13 font files (some of which were the ones that latexmk was complaining about).

The solution was to have PHP generate the LaTeX file I wanted to compile (file.tex) into a temp directory (where I had copied the fonts) where they would be compiled and then moved to where I wanted to store the output PDFs. I'll explain with an example:

```
file_put_contents('~/website/latexFiles/temp/file.tex', $latex_data);
exec('/usr/bin/latexmk -pdf -cd ~/website/latexFiles/temp/file.tex');
exec('mv ~/website/latexFiles/temp/file.pdf ~/website/pdfs/desiredFilename.pdf');
exec('rm ~/website/latexFiles/temp/file.*');
```

So the first line generates the latex file in the directory where I'm going to compile to PDF (where $latex_data is a string containing the LaTeX document I want to create).

Now, **the part that makes this all work** is creating a directory in `~/website/latexFiles/temp` called `$HOME`. Then copying (or maybe linking, but I copied) `~/.texmf-var` into `~/website/latexFiles/temp/$HOME`. This is the path that `latexmk` will look into for the fonts it needs. Use the `-cd` switch so that latexmk moves into `~/website/latexFiles/temp` before trying to compile the LaTeX file, where it will then be able to fine the fonts.

The third line copies the `.pdf` file out to where I eventually wanted the output file and the last line removes all the remaining files from the temp directory with the same filename. I make sure I use unique filenames for the `.tex` files so I'm not removing files that another user may be generating.

Hopefully someone else finds this useful.

Comment: Although this worked, this solution is not as suited at that of AaL's. For anyone else with this problem, please follow his directions before attempting this as a solution.