# How do I compile .tex file from a PHP script? How do I set sudoers?

Tags: php, apache, tex

I wish to compile a .tex file from within a php script, but compilation partly fails (some fonts are not rendered - see log below).
I am sure .tex file is fine, and I compile it fine from my shell as root (on a Fedora 17 machine).
Issue seems to be that apache user has restricted permissions.

I am trying to set permission into the /etc/sudoers, but I not sure how to write them. I tried without success.

```
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/latex 
                       /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/biber 
                       /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex
                       /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/*
```

missfont.log is created and it has

```
mktextfm larm1728
mktextfm larm1000
mktextfm larm1200
```

I tried to locate larm1728, but it is not there.

Help is very welcome, thks

---

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T2A+wncyr on input line 2.

LaTeX Font Info:    No file T2Awncyr.fd. on input line 2.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/wncyr/m/n' undefined (Font)  using `T2A/cmr/m/n'  instead on input line 2.

Font T2A/cmr/m/n/17.28=larm1728 at 17.28pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
               relax 
l.2 ...xtcyrillic{Коминтерн}}{Komintern}}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! Font T2A/wncyr/m/n/17.28=larm1728 at 17.28pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file 
not found.
```

---

I have some update:

I gave to user apache a shell, and then this is what i got:

```
bash-4.2$ /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/latex MyFile.tex
------
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/wncyr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 2.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm larm1728
mkdir: cannot create directory `././var/www/.texlive2013': 
Permission denied 
mktextfm: mktexdir /var/www/.texlive2013/texmf-var/fonts/tfm/lh/lh-t2a failed.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/17.28=larm1728 at 17.28pt not loadable: Metric (TFM)
```

(btw, why that warning does not show up in the log file?)

now, setting

```
chown apache:apache /var/www/
```

i get instead

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/wncyr/m/n' undefined (Font)   
using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 2.
kpathsea: Running mktextfm larm1728
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1;
nonstopmode; input larm1728
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea: Running mktexmf larm1728
mktexmf: /var/www/.texlive2013/texmf-var/fonts/source/lh/lh-t2a/larm1728.mf: 
successfully generated.
--snip--
```

then i run

```
bash-4.2$ /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/biber  MyFile.bcf
bash-4.2$ /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex  MyFile.tex
```

and output is very fine.

Similarly, if a run

```
bash-4.2$ php direct.php    # direct.php is below
```

**BUT if I call localhost//direct.php from my client, it still
fails.**

I am missing something, but what?
thanks 
mario

```
direct.php

<?php

echo '<hr>';
$nomeFile = 'MyFile';

$texFile = $nomeFile.".tex";
$bibFile = $nomeFile.'.bcf';
$pdfFile = $nomeFile.".pdf";

$test2 = `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/latex  --interaction
batchmode $texFile`;
$test21 = `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/biber    $bibFile`;
$test22 = `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex
--interaction batchmode $texFile`;

echo "<pre>$test2</pre>";
echo "<pre>$test21</pre>";
echo "<pre>$test22</pre>";

echo "<br><a href=\"$texFile\">$texFile</a>";
echo "<br><a href=\"$pdfFile\">$pdfFile</a>";
?>
```

Comment: does it compile fine if you log in as the apache user and try to compile?

Comment: login as apache? do you mean login into Fedora 17, or sudo apache? which password? (su apache
This account is currently not available.)

Comment: Whichever user is running Apache, not the user with the name apache (necessarily).

Comment: you're not showing how you actually execute your commands ($test2 etc). Add that to your question.

Comment: eis, I am not sure about what you ask. How should I execute $test? It is just that, by backticks (``), or not?

Comment: I run with similar problem and it was solved by setting $HOME environment variable to /var/www in a shell-script which invoked pdflatex (or I believe any folder writeable to www-data is ok here). See the details on [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289251/mktextfm-fails-when-pdflatex-is-invoked-by-cgi-bin-script-under-www-data-apache/289252#289252).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get PHP to compile a LaTeX document if it (www-data) can't get access to the required packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240725/how-can-i-get-php-to-compile-a-latex-document-if-it-www-data-cant-get-access)